# Condicional if Evaluo un numero par mayor de 20

Tags: java

Hola chicos estoy evaluando que segun el numero y el rango, a traves de condicionales if me devuelva un mensaje u otro. No consigo entender porque al introducir el numero 24 me sale el mensaje "Weird" y a continuacion "Not Weird" ya que solo me debería salir "Not Weird" ¿Porque? si se ve explicitamente en el ultimo if que si el numero es par y es mayor de 20 me imprima "Not Weird". no se si ya me he bloqueado y hay algo que no estoy viendo, ya que el if penultimo condiciona si es mayor o igual a 6 y tambien menor o igual a 20. No se porque no entiendo lo que esta pasando. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("introduce un numero");
        int N = sc.nextInt();

        if (N / 2 != 0) {

            System.out.println("Weird");

        }

        if (N %2 == 0 && N == 2 && N < 5) {

            System.out.println("Not Weird");

        }

        if (N %2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20) {

            System.out.println("Weird");

        }
        if (N %2 == 0 && N > 20) {

            System.out.println("Not Weird");

        }
```

Comment: Sin meterme a mirar si las condiciones están correctas (asumamos que si), los `if` no son *excluyentes*... que entre por un `if` no significa que no vaya a entrar a otro! Para eso se usa un `if` seguido de `else if`, en vez de `if`. De esa manera una vez que entre a uno de ellos dejará de evaluar los demás. Si utilizas solo `if`s, pues los evaluará todos uno tras otro y ejecutará todos los que cumplan la condición

Comment: Ya lo he probado y sigue sin salir como deberia.Lo curioso es que entra en el if y pone clarisimamente que tiene que ser menor o igual a 20. ¿ porque se ejecuta ese if si solo cumple con la condicion de que es par pero no que se menor que 20. es verdad que pone tambien que mayor o igual a 6 y menor o igual a 20. Entiendo que al estar separado por && debe cumplir todas y cada una de las condiciones y que, aunque cumpla dos de las condiciones, si no cumple una tercera no debería ejecutarse. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

> al introducir el numero 24 me sale el mensaje "Weird" y a continuacion
> "Not Weird" ya que solo me debería salir "Not Weird" ¿Porque?

`24 / 2` tiene como resultado 12 y en este punto indica que si este valor es diferente (`!=`) a 0 imprimira "Weird".

```
if (N / 2 != 0) {
   System.out.println("Weird");
}
```

Si deseas que ùnicamente imprima "Not Weird" deberìas usar el operador `%`, en este caso `24 % 2` tiene como resultado 0 por lo tanto no entrarìa en esta condiciòn

```
   if (N % 2 != 0) {

         System.out.println("Weird");

   }
```

Comment: Perdona el primer if deberia ser if (N %2 != 0)// imprime Weird. ¿haciendo eso estoy evaluando que sea par no?

Comment: Asì es si el resultado de N % 2 es igual a 0  es un numero par

Comment: Gracias chicos por vuestros comentarios, ya lo he conseguido,  era la tonteria de que en vez de % puse / para evaluar los pares. No se como no lo he podido ver.

Comment: Hola Javier no te preocupes asì nos sucede a todos, un poco de experiencia y listo.